# Is there an antonym for "paucity" that means not scarce and not necessarily but possibly enough?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, formality

I am trying to fill in the blank in this sentence: "There is a(n) ___ of research on this topic."

Using the word paucity would imply, to me, that I feel there is definitely not enough research and more needs to be done. However, what I am trying to say is that I know some amount of research has been done on the topic, and while there are certainly gaps in the knowledge yet to be filled, there is enough to justify a systematic review of the literature on the topic.

The best word I've been able to come up with is abundance, but I don't think it's quite what I am looking for because I feel it implies that the topic is very well understood and further research is not necessary.

Another possible answer would be "good amount". I think this fits my needs, but doesn't sound formal enough, as this is for an academic paper.

A practical example of what I mean is this:
Suppose you are driving on the highway with about 1/8 a tank of gas left and approaching an exit that has a gas station but no restaurant. Your passenger asks if you should stop for gas at this exit or wait for the next one so you can get lunch at the same time. Being away from home, you don't actually know how far the next exit with a gas station is, but because your car gets pretty good mileage and the area isn't extraordinarily rural you assume you have enough gas to get to the next exit and decide to stay on the highway. How could you describe this amount of fuel?

Comment: What did a thesaurus suggest to you that didn't work?

Comment: what's wrong with 'some research'?

Comment: @Mitch - e.g. Plethora, abundance, modicum. Basically nothing that was agnostic as to whether the amount was enough or too little.

Comment: @JeffUK - I feel like 'some research' would either sound too informal, or need to be followed by a ", but ...".

Comment: @bashtown "Some" is agnostic as to whether the amount is too much or too little!

Comment: In fact, why add another word at all,  "There is research on this topic."

Comment: There is a body of research—small, large, early, recent, whatever. Decide what you want to say and say it.

Comment: @JeffUK and then  delete the whole sentence because it adds nothing to the paper - or continue with ", but little of it is recent" or whatever

Comment: The opposite phrase (antonym) is "wealth" - *There is a wealth of research on this topic*.  I don't think that's what you want - you're not looking for an antonym.

Comment: adequecy......?

Comment: If there is some research, but you don't want to say anything as to whether or not it's enough research, why mention it at all? Just leave the sentence out entirely.

Comment: @barbecue The intended meaning is that there's enough literature to summarize in a review but not necessarily enough that the field is completely explored.

Comment: How about **surfeit**?

Comment: *adequacy*.....

Comment: glut; adequate; sufficient.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that you've written a sentence form that appears in many introductions of technical manuscripts with a different meaning: "There was a sparsity/paucity of research in this area[, motivating me to work on it]."

It's a given that more research can be performed; it's not necessary to inform the reader of this. It sounds like you mean something like the following:

> The study of A has emerged as a distinct field that now merits a review.

> There is now **sufficient** research on this active topic to review it.

> This burgeoning field is now broad **enough** to usefully review.

> An **appreciable**/**considerable**/**notable** amount of work has recently been published in this developing area, prompting this review.

Does this match the intended meaning?

Comment: I am an engineering grad student working to develop flood risk models to predict effects on human health after a flood event. The project I am working on now is a systematic literature review to identify available quantitative findings linking flood events to health outcomes.

I have developed a conceptual model based on some foundational papers in the field of disaster-health epidemiology, and I am reviewing subsequent empirical epidemiological research to fill in the quantitative relationships between variables in my model.

Comment: I know there is some research in this area, but not being in the field of epidemiology myself, I don't want to imply that there is or isn't a need for more research in that field, just that I believe there is already enough for me to get started on my work.

Comment: Any of the above four examples meets these requirements.

Comment: I like your second suggestion because it specifically relates the sufficiency of the amount of research to my needs, not to the topic more broadly.

Comment: It is indeed the least committal statement (and the closest to the requested template "There is...research on this topic"). Thank you for the upvote!

Answer (score 15):

**sufficiency**

> the state of being sufficient (MW)

**adequate** *body of literature* on this topic (to justify this survey)

> of a level of quality that meets one's needs or standards (MW)

Comment: Adequate (especially if italicised) gives the best 'most likely good enough, but definitely could be better' definition OP seems to be looking for

Comment: "Reasonable sufficiency" would introduce the idea that the amount existing reasearch is only just adequate.

Comment: I have heard "bare sufficiency" on occasion.

Comment: good stuff. hopefully one of these works for OP and others in their situation.

Answer (score 13):

I would propose **limited**. Saying,

> There is a *limited* amount of research on this topic.

would imply that, although there is some research that has been done and published on the topic, there isn't very much. There being a limited amount of research doesn't pass judgment on the *quality* of the research that has been done, and it's entirely possible that, even with a limited amount, some important conclusions can be drawn and a decent understanding of the overall topic can be cobbled together.

This seems to fit your intended meaning quite well.

That said, I would generally opt to go with [Chemomechanics's suggestions](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/569622) to reword your sentence entirely, obviating the need for a "single-word request".

Answer (score 6):

If you wanted to fill in the blank exactly as written, you could go with

> There is a modicum of research on this subject.

Answer (score 6):

"**Modicum**" expresses that there is a quantity, usually of a desired thing, and implies that more may be desirable; essentially it means "some" or a small amount.  For example, a modicum of research has been done in this area.

It may be better to use the more informative sentence that you put after your "what I am trying to say is ...".

Answer (score 5):

**substantial** or **significant** means more than a little but not necessarily enough. **non-trivial** is an even more direct antonym of 'sparse/ity' or 'little' or 'paucity', but slightly arch.

But I do not agree with your highway example for 'more than a little but not necessarily enough'. If I think I have enough fuel, even if it's only a little, I'll stay on. If I think I don't have enough fuel, it's not safe to continue, regardless of how small or large that amount is. Plus, with GPS nav I *do* know both how far the next exit is *and* whether there's a restaurant -- and maybe even if it's a good one :-)

Comment: I've heard "non-trivial" many times in this context for Computer Science. It can be used sarcastically to mean a huge amount, but more often it means "it's trivial. Well, it's more than that, but still trivial. OK, it's even more than that, pushing it into non-trivial territory".

Answer (score 4):

> How could you describe this amount of fuel?

**enough**

OED

> A. adj. (determiner).
>
> I. **As much or as many as required or wanted; sufficient in quantity or number.**
>
> 1934   Butler (Georgia) Herald 16 Aug. 2/6   *Heat and cold are cruel things, but man has intelligence enough to overcome them.*
>
> 2016   Church Times 9 Dec. 11/2   *The Archbishop of Mosul, Mor Nicodemus Daoud Sharaf, and the Archbishop of St Matthew's..were denied visas..because they did not have enough money.*

Comment: No, I was specifically looking for a word that did not clearly indicate if the amount was enough. You're not certain you have enough to make it to the next exit, but you do know that you have enough gas to continue for some distance beyond the present exit.

Comment: @bashtown: you wrote *"you assume you have enough gas to get to the next exit and decide to stay on the highway."* There is nothing in your question to suggest that *"You're not certain"* I note you have accepted *sufficient* which also does **not** indicate *"You're not certain"*.

Answer (score 2):

A plain **some**, as JeffUK suggested in a comment, would fit very well. It acknowledges existence without qualification, perhaps with a hint that it is not complete: "While there is **some [existing] research** on this topic more work needs to be done."

"Some" can be accompanied to further describe the nature or amount of the research. Some of these examples are from other answers: some ***initial* or *basic*** research, some ***substantial* or *considerable*** research. If it is unsystematic, one could call it some ***scattered* or *haphazard*** research.

A small, uncoordinated effort one could call "a **[*smattering*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smattering) of research".**

Answer (score 2):

I would say, "the research on this topic is inexhaustive", and leave it as a matter of insinuation that I'm not rebuking the research for not being good enough, only that it has not exhausted all the research avenues.

Another possibility is "there is foundational research on this topic". This conveys the idea that the groundwork has been adequately laid, but the topic isn't closed; we could add a qualifier to *topic*: "there exists foundational research about this open topic".

Answer (score 1):

Possibly "**ample**" works for you.

As per [The American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.wordnik.com/words/ample)

> adj.  Of large or great size, amount, extent, or capacity: synonym:
> spacious.
> adj.    Fully sufficient to meet a need or purpose: synonym:
> plentiful.

Here, we'd be wanting the 2nd definition. To fit your sentence structure, it would be:

> There is an ample amount of research.

Answer (score 0):

The antonym of paucity is **abundance**, per *Oxford American Writer’s Thesaurus*.

> There is an **abundance** of research…